# Azure Pipeline equivalent variable of GITHUB_ENV

Tags: python-3.x, azure-pipelines

I'm new to Azure Pipeline and I'm converting yaml file for Github action to Azure Pipleline.
Currently I'm using a python script to set session tokens. Here is the piece of the python code.

```
env_file = os.getenv('GITHUB_ENV')

with open(env_file, "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("sessionId=" + data['userInfo']['sessionId'] + "\n")
    myfile.write("uat_sessionId=" + uat_data['userInfo']['sessionId'] + "\n")
```

Since I'm using Azure Pipeline instead of Github action, what variable in Azure Pipeline is equivalent to **GITHUB_ENV** that I can use.
Thanks in advance!

Tried to find an equivalent variable in the predefine variables in Azure but can't find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Azure DevOps does not have a variable or system similar to the **GITHUB_ENV** variable I know of. There is a way of reusing variables set in an earlier stage/job/step. But it will be more cumbersome to implement.

See [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks) to get more info on output from tasks.